# Nagle-Like Problem

Tags: tcp, network-programming, real-time, asyncsocket, sfml

so I have this real-time game, with a C++ sever with disabled nagle using [SFML library](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) , and client using [asyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/), also disables nagle. I'm sending 30 packets every 1 second. There is no problem sending from the client to the server, but when sending from the server to the clients, some of the packets are migrating. For example, if I'm sending "a" and "b" in completly different packets, the client reads it as "ab". It's happens just once a time, but it makes a real problem in the game.

So what should I do? How can I solve that? Maybe it's something in the server? Maybe OS settings?

To be clear: I AM NOT using nagle but I still have this problem. I disabled in both client and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You have to disable Nagle in both peers</strike>. You might want to find a different protocol that's record-based such as `SCTP`.

#### EDIT2

Since you are asking for a protocol here's how I would do it:

- Define a header for the message. Let's say I would pick a 32 bits header.

  ```
  Header:
      MSG Length: 16b
      Version: 8b
      Type: 8b
  ```
- Then the real message comes in, having `MSG Length` bytes.

So now that I have a format, how would I handle things ?

#### Server

When I write a message, I prepend the control information (the length is the most important, really) and send the whole thing. Having NODELAY enabled or not makes no difference.

#### Client

I continuously receive stuff from the server, right ? So I have to do some sort of `read`.

- Read bytes from the server. Any amount can arrive. Keep reading until you've got at least 4 bytes.
- Once you have these 4 bytes, interpret them as the header and extract the `MSG Length`
- Keep reading until you've got at least `MSG Length` bytes. Now you've got your message and can process it

This works regardless of TCP options (such as NODELAY), MTU restrictions, etc.

Comment: I did disabled both. I checked for SCTP and TCP seems better for MMO real time games.

Comment: @Eli how does it seem better ?

Comment: That's not the question here, right now this is my problem, maybe if I will decide to change it it will take me a lot of time to change all my code, so right now I want to solve that problem, because it should not be like that.

Comment: @Eli So it **doesn't** seem better. I knew it's not convenient but I was trying to provoke you into admitting you don't actually have arguments :-)

Comment: I don't understand. Most of the MMO real time games uses TCP without having this problem, so I need to use SCTP? Sure I can edit my code for this TCP problem to work better - but it really should be like that?

Comment: @Eli I'm on your side, but why can't you just receive 'ab' and treat it as if there's 2 messages ?!

Comment: What do you mean? How can I know that ab is 2 messages and not one?

Comment: @Eli Use a delimiter ? `|a||b|` Use some protocol, with a header length ? The options are endless.

Comment: OK I am considering changing my protocol. I did changed my code, but now I have HUGE gaps between any packet. I don't know why. So what would be the best for positions? UDP? Can you explain a bit about SCTP?

Comment: Nagle does not delay the first packet (of a row of packets). It neither delays any packets if the receiver acknowledges the previous packets quickly. So disabling Nagle does not help much here. It just might raise the chances a little bit to receive the data in the same packets as you sent it.

Comment: @hagello Duh. Mentioning Nagle in this was bs, I take it all back. Come to think of it I would delete this whole answer if I could.

Answer (score 3):

> For example, if I'm sending "a" and "b" in completly different packets, the client reads it as "ab". It's happens just once a time, but it makes a real problem in the game.

I think you have lost sight of the fundamental nature of TCP: it is a stream protocol, not a packet protocol. TCP neither respects nor preserves the sender's data boundaries. To put it another way, TCP is free to combine (or split!) the "packets" you send, and present them on the receiver any way its wants. The only restriction that TCP honors is this: if a byte is delivered, it will be delivered in the same order in which it was sent. (And nothing about Nagle changes this.)

So, if you invoke `send` (or `write`) on the server twice, sending these six bytes:

```
"packet" 1: A B C
"packet" 2: D E F
```

Your client side might `recv` (or `read`) any of these sequences of bytes:

```
ABC / DEF
ABCDEF
AB / CD / EF
```

If your application requires knowledge of the boundaries between the sender's `write`s, then it is your responsibility to preserve and transmit that information.

As others have said, there are many ways to go about that. You could, for example, send a newline after each quantum of information. This is (in part) how HTTP, FTP, and SMTP work.

You could send the packet length along with the data. The generalized form for this is called TLV, for "Type, Length, Value". Send a fixed-length type field, a fixed-length length field, and then an arbitrary-length value. This way you know when you have read the entire value and are ready for the next TLV.

You could arrange that every packet you send is identical in length.

I suppose there are other solutions, and I suppose that you can think of them on your own. But first you have to realize this: TCP can *and will* merge or break your application packets. You can rely upon the order of the bytes' delivery, but nothing else.